# FileChooser - How to show an error message while Saving json file as png or any other format

Tags: java, json, swing, javafx-8

1. In javafx, create dummy json data,
2. Create Filechooser object, save dummy json data into a file as Products.json
3. If User save File as Products.png or products.xml or any other format, i want to see a error popop, 'Please save file as json'

**FileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Json doc(*.json)", "*.json"));**
- Tried above code, it will filter only json files but still i can able to save as other format.

1. Expecting to display an error messages popup if I save json file with other extensions.
2. Actual result - I can still able to save json file as png or other formats

Comment: Are you using Swing or JavaFX (you've tagged both)? For JavaFX, when the user clicks save you will get the resulting `File` object which you can check and display an error if the extension is invalid.

Comment: Don’t confuse file types with file name suffixes. The user should not be enforced to add a suffix which your program can add. Just check whether the name ends with the desired suffix and append it when not.

Comment: @Slaw I am using javaFX, yes from the file extension i can able to validate, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly you want the user to be able to save the file as whatever they want, but if they save it as anything other than .json, to get an error message.
If that's the case, this is what you want to do:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

// your code

String filename = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
   if (!filename.endsWith(".json"))
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You should save the file with a .json extension!");
```

If you want to fix the extension you can add:

```
filename += ".json";
```

Comment: Hi, I can able to fix my issue from the File object after opening FileChooser.